# My vpn is connected but i cannot browse internet

Tags: linux, networking, router, vpn, dns

i have problem with vpn recently
i can connect with vpn but not with internet, ping shows up to 200ms more.

```
mtr -rw api.protonvpn.ch


Start: 2021-11-20T16:49:27+0700
HOST: nonely                                         Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- 192.168.90.1                                  0.0%    10    3.6   4.4   2.6  12.9   3.0
  2.|-- 172.16.16.199                                 0.0%    10   22.0  25.4  19.8  40.4   6.8
  3.|-- 172-13-1-199.lightspeed.mssnks.sbcglobal.net  0.0%    10   20.6  24.6  13.8  37.0   7.3
  4.|-- 10.5.192.1                                    0.0%    10   22.1 123.6  22.1 375.5 126.4
  5.|-- 180.252.1.161                                 0.0%    10   32.4 109.4  15.8 377.2 122.8
  6.|-- 180.240.190.109                              60.0%    10   60.5 158.1  60.5 425.5 178.4
  7.|-- 180.240.190.109                              70.0%    10   46.3 103.0  46.3 201.4  85.5
  8.|-- 180.240.204.104                               0.0%    10   46.3 145.0  44.2 486.8 148.2
  9.|-- tge6-4.fr3.sin.llnw.net                       0.0%    10   45.5 142.8  41.5 500.0 152.0
10.|-- siteprotect.security.neustar                  0.0%    10   43.9 138.7  41.3 499.4 148.6
11.|-- ???                                          100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
12.|-- ???                                          100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
13.|-- ???                                          100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
14.|-- ???                                          100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
15.|-- gre01.sin.siteprotect.security.neustar       20.0%    10   62.8 186.1  34.9 640.6 208.6
16.|-- 156.154.253.7                                 0.0%    10  240.5 317.4 227.2 677.9 148.6
17.|-- 172.17.12.19                                  0.0%    10  222.9 292.6 209.8 609.3 134.7
18.|-- 185.159.159.170                               0.0%    10  215.5 217.8 209.4 242.6   9.6




cat /etc/resolv.conf

#Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
#127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
#run "resolvectl status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
 
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 209.222.18.222
nameserver 209.222.18.218 
nameserver 192.168.90.1 
search itotolink.net

ping -c 4 api.protonvpn.ch

    PING api.protonvpn.ch (185.159.159.170) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 185.159.159.170 (185.159.159.170): icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=219 ms
64 bytes from 185.159.159.170 (185.159.159.170): icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=234 ms
64 bytes from 185.159.159.170 (185.159.159.170): icmp_seq=3 ttl=45 time=436 ms
64 bytes from 185.159.159.170 (185.159.159.170): icmp_seq=4 ttl=45 time=635 ms

nslookup api.protonvpn.ch

;; communications error to 127.0.0.1#53: connection refused
```

my nslookup is not working for all servers or url
what happend with my  configuration? hmm...
is there something wrong with my router?  I don't think so, I haven't tampered with the router settings since I bought it

Comment: Are you getting Internet from a source at the other end of your tunnel, or, do you need split tunnel to get Internet locally?

Comment: i dont know yet,but all that makes me confused, why can't I use vpn anymore, even open vpn from vpn book is the same, i can connect but i don't get internet access, currently i don't use any tunnel. please help me

Comment: Try uninstalling the VPN app and see if that returns Internet. Also Run TCP/IP Reset and restart the computer.

Comment: what is the specific command?  I use Linux nonely 5.14.0-kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.14.16-1kali1 (2021-11-05) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: i have tried uninstalling protonvpn but the problem is not in my local network, but when i connect with protonvpn i don't get internet access(i have connected with proton), 
is this possible?

/etc/network/interfaces

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

and when I see the contents of the /etc/network/interfaces.d/* folder it's nothing or empty

Comment: Who can troubleshoot the remote network for you?

Comment: i dont know, pls help me

Comment: I don't think I can assist you with the remote system.  Maybe they could uninstall, restart, and reinstall the VPN.

Comment: ok thanks, then could you please explain why with my nslookup?  so it can be an error like that?

Comment: There appears to be some issue with the remote system networking and since you cannot properly connect and do things, someone at the remote site will need to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, it turns out that the error is in the file
/etc/resolv.conf

I installed several modules for this:

```
sudo apt install openresolv easy-rsa network-manager-openvpn bind9 unbound
```

which previously contained:

```
#Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
#127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
#run "resolvectl status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
 
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 209.222.18.222
nameserver 209.222.18.218 
nameserver 192.168.90.1 
search itotolink.net
```

after installation changed to:

```
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your vpn and get a better one. The one you are using right now has spammy IPs they usually have. Get a premium vpn or a vpn that has dedicated ip offering. There are only few that provide dedicated ip with their vpn. I have been using purevpn with their dedicated ip add-on, only started using it for a month was going to keep it for a month only as it was costing a lot but then I just upgraded my plan with them for 5-years at 88% off. So, you might want to catch that or just invest in a vpn that is premium and you can afford.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).